# C++ compile time function execution

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have string tags in my code that are converted to numbers and used to search values in a tag-value structure.

I have something like this:

```
void foo()
{
    type value = search("SomeTag");
}
```

Where search is defined like this:

```
type search(const char* tag)
{
    return internal_search(toNumber(tag));
}
```

Because all the time tag is constant at compile time I want to remove the call that converts the tag to a number from search function. I know it is possible to execute some simple functions at compile time using templates (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time_function_execution), but I don't know exactly how to iterate through a null terminated string and keep intermediate values in the template. Can you give a simple sample that iterates a null terminated string and adds the chars in a public variable please?

Comment: As an alternative, maybe `toNumber` could keep a map of all the tags that it has seen, and their numerical value, so that you only have to pay the conversion cost once per tag?  It's not as efficient as using the template language to do the evaluation at compile time, but I would bet that the code will be a lot more readable and maintainable that way.

Comment: TTBOMK you can't iterate over strings at compile-time.

Comment: @aroth I think the toNumber function is faster than the search, even if I would use a log2 search.

Comment: @sbi: You sort of can; take a look at boost::mpl::string. But you have to write `'all ','your',' str','ings'` like this (taking advantage of the fact that a `char` can actually be 4 characters long).

Comment: Why doesn't search take an `int` instead of a string? That is, why must you use a string as input?

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y because search(12414121) will not have any meaning for a programmer, but search("Speed") will have. This is for debug purpose.

Comment: I see, they aren't actually numeric strings. Why not use the preprocessor and a common header file?  `#define TAG_SPEED 12414121`  You could generate this file directly from the DB.

Comment: @Pedro: I know there's hacks (`'a',' ','s','t','r','i','n','g'` would work, too), but this is not opaque to the user. You can't just take a common string and do that, you'll have to change the code calling that (compile-time) function.

Comment: @sbi: Yes, it's a bit of a pain. Do you know if user-defined literals 1) were included in the final standard 2) would enable iterating over strings?

Comment: @Pedro Because I don't want to recompile all project when I add a new tag. If I will have a common header for all tags that means that the header will be included all over the project and any change will recompile all project. If I will have local define maybe I will have tag conflicts or same tag with different values. I want to avoid this kind of logical errors.

Comment: @Felics: I think it might be better to recompile and be sure, that everything works than the solution with strings. When using a string there is a big chance that you misspell it and you get the error only at runtime. Or maybe you will need to change the string in the future and it is not that easy to change that string everywhere. I have worked on project that used strings instead of identifiers and it was a hell to maintain.

Comment: @Juraj Blaho The biggest error source is modifying existing code and with enums you will modify that code every time you add a new tag. Other problem with enums is that the tags are parsed from config files and this will limit available tags. Now if you add a new class you just add your tags in the config and your tags in the loading function from that class. You don't need to change the tags in all the project because they are not unique for the project, they are custom for every class.

Comment: @Felics: Probably I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you elaborate a little more about it in the problem description? There is usually a better solution than using string tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot operate on string literals at compile-time, so what you want isn't feasible in the way you suggested. However, if you're contemplating to process these strings at compile-time, then this means you know all strings at compile-time, and from that you might arrive at acceptable approximations to what you want.

The code you showed implies that the number generation (let's call it a hash) is invoked every time someone searches for a tag. Would reducing this to one invocation be acceptable? If so, you could define constants and use these instead of strings:

```
const int SomeTag       = toNumber("SomeTag"      ); 
const int SomeOtherTag  = toNumber("SomeOtherTag" ); 
const int YetAnotherTag = toNumber("YetAnotherTag"); 
// ...
```

Then, simply replace all occurances of `search("SomeTag")` by `search(SomeTag)`.

If there's a great number of tags, typing the above could be very tedious, in which case a macro might help:

```
#define DEFINE_TAG(Tag_) const int Tag_ = toNumber(#Tag_); 

DEFINE_TAG(SomeTag); 
DEFINE_TAG(SomeOtherTag); 
DEFINE_TAG(YetAnotherTag); 
// ... 

#undef DEFINE_TAG
```

Comment: This can be a good idea because it solves the big problem from enum(I don't need to include the header in all project files and to recompile it every time I add a new tag) and from local defines(tag conflicts). The only problem here is the redefinition of same tag in different files and linker errors, but.. this can be solved with static const int instead of const int. Thanks!

Comment: So are you using strings because you don't want to the enum to be included everywhere? I suppose you are aware that you're actually trading compile-time performance for run-time safety there? Is this really worth it? What I have done in the past in such cases was to break down the value space (in your case: `enum` values) into independent chunks (you'd have to use `const int` instead) which are defined in different headers. Then you only include the one header you're interested in, and aren't affected by changes in other headers.

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like what you want is [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[MPL](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/)'s [`boost::mpl::string`](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/string.html). It would be more-or-less trivial to write a metafunction to convert an `mpl::string` to an integral type at compile time using [`mpl::fold`](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/fold.html) (or fail to compile if the string literal does not represent a valid integral value).

**EDIT:**

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, so here is effectively two different answers depending on interpretation:

---

***IF*** what you're looking for is compile-time string-to-integral-value *conversion* (e.g. so `"425897"` could be recognized as the integral constant `425897` at compile time), then one can use Boost.MPL as I suggested:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_signed.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/and.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/char.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/end.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/find_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/integral_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/minus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/negate.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/next.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/not.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pair.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pop_front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/reverse_fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/size_t.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/string.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/times.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

namespace details
{
    namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

    typedef mpl::vector10<
        mpl::char_<'0'>, mpl::char_<'1'>, mpl::char_<'2'>, mpl::char_<'3'>,
        mpl::char_<'4'>, mpl::char_<'5'>, mpl::char_<'6'>, mpl::char_<'7'>,
        mpl::char_<'8'>, mpl::char_<'9'>
    > valid_chars_t;

    template<typename IntegralT, typename PowerT>
    struct power_of_10;

    template<typename IntegralT, std::size_t Power>
    struct power_of_10<IntegralT, mpl::size_t<Power> > : mpl::times<
        power_of_10<IntegralT, mpl::size_t<Power - 1u> >,
        mpl::integral_c<IntegralT, 10>
    > { };

    template<typename IntegralT>
    struct power_of_10<IntegralT, mpl::size_t<1u> >
        : mpl::integral_c<IntegralT, 10>
    { };

    template<typename IntegralT>
    struct power_of_10<IntegralT, mpl::size_t<0u> >
        : mpl::integral_c<IntegralT, 1>
    { };

    template<typename IntegralT, typename StringT>
    struct is_negative : mpl::and_<
        boost::is_signed<IntegralT>,
        boost::is_same<
            typename mpl::front<StringT>::type,
            mpl::char_<'-'>
        >
    > { };

    template<typename IntegralT, typename StringT>
    struct extract_actual_string : mpl::eval_if<
        is_negative<IntegralT, StringT>,
        mpl::pop_front<StringT>,
        mpl::identity<StringT>
    > { };

    template<typename ExtractedStringT>
    struct check_valid_characters : boost::is_same<
        typename mpl::find_if<
            ExtractedStringT,
            mpl::not_<mpl::contains<valid_chars_t, mpl::_> >
        >::type,
        typename mpl::end<ExtractedStringT>::type
    > { };

    template<typename ExtractedStringT>
    struct pair_digit_with_power : mpl::first<
        typename mpl::reverse_fold<
            ExtractedStringT,
            mpl::pair<mpl::vector0<>, mpl::size_t<0> >,
            mpl::pair<
                mpl::push_back<
                    mpl::first<mpl::_1>,
                    mpl::pair<mpl::_2, mpl::second<mpl::_1> >
                >,
                mpl::next<mpl::second<mpl::_1> >
            >
        >::type
    > { };

    template<typename IntegralT, typename ExtractedStringT>
    struct accumulate_digits : mpl::fold<
        typename pair_digit_with_power<ExtractedStringT>::type,
        mpl::integral_c<IntegralT, 0>,
        mpl::plus<
            mpl::_1,
            mpl::times<
                mpl::minus<mpl::first<mpl::_2>, mpl::char_<'0'> >,
                power_of_10<IntegralT, mpl::second<mpl::_2> >
            >
        >
    > { };

    template<typename IntegralT, typename StringT>
    class string_to_integral_impl
    {
        BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((boost::is_integral<IntegralT>));

        typedef typename extract_actual_string<
            IntegralT,
            StringT
        >::type ExtractedStringT;
        BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((check_valid_characters<ExtractedStringT>));

        typedef typename accumulate_digits<
            IntegralT,
            ExtractedStringT
        >::type ValueT;

    public:
        typedef typename mpl::eval_if<
            is_negative<IntegralT, StringT>,
            mpl::negate<ValueT>,
            mpl::identity<ValueT>
        >::type type;
    };
}

template<typename IntegralT, typename StringT>
struct string_to_integral2
    : details::string_to_integral_impl<IntegralT, StringT>::type
{ };

template<typename IntegralT, int C0, int C1 = 0, int C2 = 0,
    int C3 = 0, int C4 = 0, int C5 = 0, int C6 = 0, int C7 = 0>
struct string_to_integral : string_to_integral2<
    IntegralT,
    boost::mpl::string<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7>
> { };
```

Usage would look like:

```
type search(int tag) { /*impl... */ }

void foo()
{
    type value = search(string_to_integral<int, '4258','97'>::value);
}

// OR, if you still want to maintain the separation
// between `search` and `internal_search`

type internal_search(int tag) { /*impl... */ }

template<typename TagStringT>
type search()
{
    return internal_search(string_to_integral2<int, TagStringT>::value);
}

void foo()
{
    typedef boost::mpl::string<'4258','97'> tag_t;
    type value = search<tag_t>();
}
```

Support for negative numbers is implemented, support for overflow detection is not (but your compiler will probably give a warning).

---

***IF*** what you're looking for is compile-time string-to-integral-value *mapping* (e.g. so `"SomeTag"` could be recognized as the integral constant `425897` at compile time), then Boost.MPL still solves the problem, but all string-to-integral-value mappings must be known at compile time and registered centrally:

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/integral_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/map.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pair.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/string.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/void.hpp>

namespace details
{
    namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

    typedef mpl::map<
        mpl::pair<
            mpl::string<'Some','Tag'>,
            mpl::integral_c<int, 425897>
        >,
        mpl::pair<
            mpl::string<'Some','Othe','rTag'>,
            mpl::integral_c<int, -87>
        >,
        mpl::pair<
            mpl::string<'AnUn','sign','edTa','g'>,
            mpl::integral_c<unsigned, 7u>
        >
    > mappings_t;

    template<typename StringT>
    struct map_string_impl
    {
        typedef typename mpl::at<
            mappings_t,
            StringT
        >::type type;
        BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_NOT((boost::is_same<type, mpl::void_>));
    };
}

template<typename StringT>
struct map_string2 : details::map_string_impl<StringT>::type { };

template<int C0, int C1 = 0, int C2 = 0, int C3 = 0,
    int C4 = 0, int C5 = 0, int C6 = 0, int C7 = 0>
struct map_string : map_string2<
    boost::mpl::string<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7>
> { };
```

Usage would look like:

```
type search(int tag) { /*impl... */ }

void foo()
{
    type value = search(map_string<'Some','Tag'>::value);
}

// OR, if you still want to maintain the separation
// between `search` and `internal_search`

type internal_search(int tag) { /*impl... */ }

template<typename TagStringT>
type search()
{
    return internal_search(map_string2<TagStringT>::value);
}

void foo()
{
    typedef boost::mpl::string<'Some','Tag'> tag_t;
    type value = search<tag_t>();
}
```

`mappings_t` is what needs to be edited to maintain your string-to-integral-value mappings, and, as demonstrated, the mapped integral values need not all be of the same underlying type.

---

In either case, because the mapping is done at compile time, `search`/`internal_search` (the one with the real implementation taking an `int`) could be made to take the integral value as a template parameter rather than as a function parameter if doing so makes sense for its implementation.

Hopefully this answers your questions.

Comment: I would not go as far as saying that it is trivial (at least not for me), but it can be done.

Comment: Please give me an implementation. This is the most voted answer, but I think it's not possible to do this, as others said. I'll up vote when I'll have a full answer.

Comment: @Felics : Edited with full implementations. I gave two approaches, since it's not clear to me what you're really looking for...

Comment: I need to map a string to an int something like "SomeTag" to 1234567 and you answer is wrong because you map int to int('abcd' is int, not string)

Comment: @Felics : The definition of a string is: a sequence of characters. While `'Some'`'s direct type may be `int`, *semantically* it is exposed via `boost::mpl::string` as a sequence of characters, so it is in fact a string. What you're really saying is that you don't like the **syntax** of `'Some','Tag'` vs. `"SomeTag"`, which is something you could have determined **days** before I typed out the code for you, and saved me the trouble; but they are, in fact, both strings. In the future, read the docs you're linked to before wasting someone else's time asking for code then trivially dismissing it.

Answer (score 2):

If the string literal is known at compile time, then there is probably no reason to use it as a string literal. You may use enumeration or named integral constants.

If the string is passed to the search function by a variable and it is not known at compile time, then there is no way to do the `toNumber()` resulution at compile time. Then a good solution is to use some kind of a dictionary (e.g. `std::map<std::string, int>`)

Comment: As I said before, toNumber function is faster than the search.

Comment: I think the first paragraph here is the key. To do this at compile-time, you would need to know all possible strings at compile-time. And when you have those, there's no reason to not to use symbolic constants for them.

Answer (score 0):

Althrough not compile time, I think this is fast enough for you;

```
void foo()
{
    const static auto someTagN = toNumber("SomeTag");
    type value = internal_search(someTagN );
}
```

Comment: That won't run at compile-time, but at global construction time instead, so it will prolong the program startup.

Comment: This is what I want to avoid, string conversion at run time. I don't a few tags that are use many times, I have different tags that are used only once or few times.

Comment: @Jan Hudec It will run when foo is called first time, but if foo will be called once this has no optimization effect because the tag will be converted once at run time like it was before and I will have global memory full with junk numbers that will not be used anymore.

Comment: @Jan: Actually, local `static` variables are initialized when program execution passes their initialization code for the first time. In plain English: `someTagN` is initialized when `foo()` is called for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is probably not fashionable, but you can generate a hash-table ahead of time. I like to use gperf to generate the plumbing there.

I know know. You wanted something to make compilation last longer... Just saying :)

Comment: That's not a problem, for debug it may be #define X(tag) toNumber(tag) and for release #define X(tag) someTemplate<tag>::number. This is for run time optimizations, and compile time is irrelevant.

Comment: I was half joking, I'm not worried about compile times :)

Comment: Compile time is a big problem. In my current project a full rebuild can take several hours, and this is a very big problem:)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can.  Is the list of possible tags small?  Even if not, is it small most of the time.  If so, you can use template specialization on a subset of the tags

```
template<char *tag> 
int toNumber() {
    return toNumber(tag);
}

template<>
int toNumber<"0">() {
     return 0;
}

template<>
int toNumber<"1">() {
     return 1;
}
```

(caveats: my specialization syntax might be wrong, and I have no idea if this works for char*)

Comment: Templates don't accept character literals, only addresses of constants. So you'd have to create `const char * const` variables for the strings and pass those constants to the templates.

Comment: String literals are lvalues and consequently cannot be compile-time constants. However, *character* literals can indeed be compile-time constants.