# static conversion of integer constant to const char*

Tags: c++, c

I have an integer constant known at compile time (but not at code-writing time) and I would like to generate, also at compile time, a `const char*` holding them as ASCII. For example

```
const int  C         = IntegerConst;
const char*C_as_text = StaticConvert(A);
```

such that if `IntegerConst` is given in some `#include`d header file, say `IntegerConst=42`, than `C_as_text="42"`.

Any idea how to get such a `StaticConvert()` functionality? In principle this must be possible, as the compiler and preprocessor have all the necessary information at hand.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713420/c-convert-integer-to-string-at-compile-time.

Comment: If the number is itself a constant expression that's the result of some computation (maybe `sizeof(MyType)`?), we could discuss a template solution...

Answer (score 3):

You can use preprocessor directive:

```
#define StaticConvert(N) #N
```

Here the condition is that you need to provide the number itself as `N`. e.g.

```
const int C = 42;
const char *C_as_test = StaticConvert(42);
```

Comment: well, this will not do in my case, since C is not a literal.

Answer (score 2):

The 'stringize' preprocessor operator:

```
#define StaticConverter(V) #V

const char *x = StaticConverter(56);
assert(x[0] == '5' && x[1] == '6' && x[2] == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [preprocessor's stringizing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx).