# Const Int declared with stoi not considered a const

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple test program using CGAL, and running into the following issue:

Point is defined above as

```
typedef K::Point_d Point;
```

but I don't think this is relevant.

When I attempt to compile the program as follows:

```
const int size = 10;
Point P[size];
```

g++ does so without issue.

If instead I attempt to compile:

```
const int size = stoi("10");
Point P[size]
```

I get the following error

```
error: variable length array of non-POD element type 'Point' (aka 'Point_d<Cartesian_d<double,
  CGAL::Linear_algebraCd<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > > >')
```

Why is size considered a variable instead of a const when retrieved from a string?

Comment: Const doesn't indicate a constant, it indicates a runtime variable which can't be manipulated. You need constexpr for a constant.

Comment: Because `stoi` is not marked as `constexpr`, and it probably wouldn't qualify anyway, as it deals with `std::string`, which does lots of stuff that isn't allowed in `constexpr` functions (such as memory allocation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't set variable length with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045266/cant-set-variable-length-with-variable)

Comment: In one case, the value is known at compile time. In the other case, the value may not be modified, but is now known at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

C++ defines specific things to be constant expressions that are **defined** to be known at compile time - see [constant_expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression).

In general functions that are not defined as `constexpr` are not, regardless of what you pass them. You could try and force it as such:

```
#include<string>

constexpr int x = std::stoi("10");
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

but you will find this still leads to an error:

```
error: call to non-constexpr function 'int std::stoi(const string&, std::size_t*, int)'
```

so, you are out of luck as `stoi` is not a constant expression. If you really insist you could override this using your own implementation for example that in [How do I convert a C string to a int at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195176/how-do-i-convert-a-c-string-to-a-int-at-compile-time#25195711).

Answer (score 1):

**stoi** is not evaluated at compile time. That means the compiler does not know how big the array should be.
if you want to do something like that you have to use a constexpr function ([constexpr function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)). These can be evaluated at compile time, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't understand the semantics of the `stoi` function. All it sees is you calling a function that returns an integer (whether that function can be inlined and optimized away is a seperate issue from the semantics).

To the compiler there is very little semantic difference between

```
const int size = stoi("10");
```

and

```
const int size = getchar();
```

As other answers mentioned `constexpr` being the exception. I just thought I'd illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The first `const int size = 10;` is a compile time const expression and it can be computed during compilation, 
but `const int size = stoi("10")` is not a compile time const expression hence it fails to compile.
`std::stoi` is not a `constexpr` function to evaluated on compile time.

If you want to have this functionality you may need to create a `constexpr` function to evaluate on compile time.

```
constexpr bool is_digit(char c) {
    return c <= '9' && c >= '0';
}

constexpr int stoi_impl(const char* str, int value = 0) {
    return *str ?
            is_digit(*str) ?
                stoi_impl(str + 1, (*str - '0') + value * 10)
                : throw "compile-time-error: not a digit"
            : value;
}

constexpr int to_int(const char* str) {
    return stoi_impl(str);
}


int main() {
    constexpr int size = to_int("10");
    int arr[size];
}
```

This will compile; [copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25195711/3845604)]

Answer (score 1):

In the first code sample

```
const int size = 10;
Point P[size];
```

the particular value of `size` can be used already **at compile time**, since it is known (you've specified it). Therefore the compiler may replace all its uses with particular value, w/o actually creating a variable.

In the second sample

```
const int size = stoi("10");
Point P[size]
```

the compiler cannot know the value, since it is deduced by the `stoi` function **at runtime**. Therefore it cannot substitute the size of the array (which must be known beforehand to determine now much memory to allocate), and you get the error.

In C++11 there is **constexpr** idiom, which allows some functions, declared as constexpr, be evaluated at compile time. But in your case `stoi` isn't constexpr function, so you cannot achieve what you want using this particular function. You can implement your own constexpr `stoi`, but I don't see much sence in it, since your code in this case would contain somethins like this: `my_constexpr_stoi("10")`, i.e. the argument is always manually written and always known beforehand. Why don't write just `10`?..

Answer (score 0):

To expand on kabanus’ answer, the language standard says that an array bound in C++11 must be something called an *integral constant expression*.  C++17 relaxes this slightly and allows a few more things, but that’s not important right now.

[This page at cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) lists all the things you are **not** allowed to do inside a constant expression.  It basically quotes the language standard.

The relevant section that allows your first example is 8a.  You are not allowed to use a variable, unless it’s a `const` variable initialized to a constant expression. So using the name of a `const` variable of integral type that is initialized to a constant expression **is** legal, as in your first example.  Numeric constants are constant expressions, so `size` is a `const` variable initialized to a constant expression, which is A-OK.

However, due to point 2, function calls are only constant expressions if they are both declared `constexpr` and already defined.  So, for a standard library function to be usable in an array expression in your code, it would need to be declared `constexpr` and also defined in the header file.

The standard does not say that `stoi()` qualifies, although I don’t think anything in it directly forbids some implementation from providing that as an extension.