# How do I generate an integer from a string literal at compile-time?

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor, string-literals

In C++, is it possible to generate an integer from a string literal using only compile-time facilities ?

For instance, if all we have is the literal "6", is there some way to use it as a template argument, like `std::array<GET_INTEGER("6")> a;` ?

I know about `constexpr`-based techniques, such as :

```
template <int N> constexpr char get_char(const char s[N], int n) {
  return s[n];
}
```

However `constexpr` isn't ready yet on most compilers, so I'm looking for solutions using probably macros and TMP.

It's just for experimentation, so crazy ideas are welcome.

Comment: What does "most compilers" mean?  If "most compilers" includes what are probably the most widely used compilers (gcc and Visual C++) then the answer is that it cannot be done.

Comment: Why not just write 6, without the quotes?

Comment: It could work if you use character literals `GET_INTEGER('6', '7', '8')`, but I don't think string literals will work.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis AFAIK, only gcc supports constexpr right now. (I could be wrong though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently gcc allows `"abcd"[3]` be interpreted as `'d'`, which allows this to work (at least on g++-4.6 and 4.7):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum.hpp>

template <const char... characters>
struct GetIntegerTemplate;

template <const char head, const char... rest>
struct GetIntegerTemplate<head, rest...>
{
    typedef GetIntegerTemplate<rest...> Prev;
    enum
    {
        power = Prev::power * 10,
        value = (head - '0') * Prev::power + Prev::value
    };
};

template <>
struct GetIntegerTemplate<>
{
    enum
    {
        power = 1,
        value = 0
    };
};

#define GET_NTH_CHARACTER(z, n, data) data[n]
#define GET_INTEGER(length, the_string) GetIntegerTemplate<BOOST_PP_ENUM(length, GET_NTH_CHARACTER, the_string)>::value

int main()
{
    static_assert(GET_INTEGER(7, "1234567") == 1234567, "oops");
}
```

But it won't compile on clang, which says "non-type template argument of type 'const char' is not an integral constant expression".

---

What it really does is to break down the string literal `"1234567"` into a list of character literals `'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'`. The instantiation

```
GetIntegerTemplate<'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'>::value
```

is then invoked to turn the list into an integer 1234567. The string → char literal step may involve non-standard behavior which may not work outside of g++ (i.e. worse than `constexpr` ☺), but that `GetIntegerTemplate<...>::value` is portable.

Comment: Maybe by casting to `int` ? I don't have LLVM right now, but that could be worth testing.

Comment: @kbok: The problem isn't the type, but that `"1234567"[0]` in clang is not considered a constant. This is liekly a gcc extension but I can't find anywhere mentioning this.

Comment: I see, I thought the problem was that it wasn't `integral`. MSVC doesn't like that either ("invalid template argument for 'foo', expected compile-time constant expression"); it's a shame that only gcc supports it, while it's the only compiler which supports constexpr.

Comment: As of the standard (5.19.1), "An integral constant-expression can involve only literals of arithmetic types (2.13, 3.9.1), enumerators, const variables or static data members of integral or enumeration types initialized with constant expressions
(8.5), non-type template parameters of integral or enumeration types, and sizeof expressions." So, no string literals. I think that gcc supports it as a part of `constexpr` support.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(Reposting from [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5869507/636019))</sub>

If you don't mind changing your conceptual definition of 'string literal' from e.g.
`"425897"` to `'4258','97'`, then you can use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[MPL](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/)'s [`boost::mpl::string<>`](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/string.html) to accomplish this:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_signed.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/and.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/char.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/end.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/find_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/integral_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/minus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/negate.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/next.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/not.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pair.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pop_front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/reverse_fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/size_t.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/string.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/times.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

namespace details
{
    namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

    typedef mpl::vector10<
        mpl::char_<'0'>, mpl::char_<'1'>, mpl::char_<'2'>, mpl::char_<'3'>,
        mpl::char_<'4'>, mpl::char_<'5'>, mpl::char_<'6'>, mpl::char_<'7'>,
        mpl::char_<'8'>, mpl::char_<'9'>
    > valid_chars_t;

    template<typename IntegralT, typename PowerT>
    struct power_of_10;

    template<typename IntegralT, std::size_t Power>
    struct power_of_10<IntegralT, mpl::size_t<Power> > : mpl::times<
        power_of_10<IntegralT, mpl::size_t<Power - 1u> >,
        mpl::integral_c<IntegralT, 10>
    > { };

    template<typename IntegralT>
    struct power_of_10<IntegralT, mpl::size_t<1u> >
        : mpl::integral_c<IntegralT, 10>
    { };

    template<typename IntegralT>
    struct power_of_10<IntegralT, mpl::size_t<0u> >
        : mpl::integral_c<IntegralT, 1>
    { };

    template<typename IntegralT, typename StringT>
    struct is_negative : mpl::and_<
        boost::is_signed<IntegralT>,
        boost::is_same<
            typename mpl::front<StringT>::type,
            mpl::char_<'-'>
        >
    > { };

    template<typename IntegralT, typename StringT>
    struct extract_actual_string : mpl::eval_if<
        is_negative<IntegralT, StringT>,
        mpl::pop_front<StringT>,
        mpl::identity<StringT>
    > { };

    template<typename ExtractedStringT>
    struct check_valid_characters : boost::is_same<
        typename mpl::find_if<
            ExtractedStringT,
            mpl::not_<mpl::contains<valid_chars_t, mpl::_> >
        >::type,
        typename mpl::end<ExtractedStringT>::type
    > { };

    template<typename ExtractedStringT>
    struct pair_digit_with_power : mpl::first<
        typename mpl::reverse_fold<
            ExtractedStringT,
            mpl::pair<mpl::vector0<>, mpl::size_t<0> >,
            mpl::pair<
                mpl::push_back<
                    mpl::first<mpl::_1>,
                    mpl::pair<mpl::_2, mpl::second<mpl::_1> >
                >,
                mpl::next<mpl::second<mpl::_1> >
            >
        >::type
    > { };

    template<typename IntegralT, typename ExtractedStringT>
    struct accumulate_digits : mpl::fold<
        typename pair_digit_with_power<ExtractedStringT>::type,
        mpl::integral_c<IntegralT, 0>,
        mpl::plus<
            mpl::_1,
            mpl::times<
                mpl::minus<mpl::first<mpl::_2>, mpl::char_<'0'> >,
                power_of_10<IntegralT, mpl::second<mpl::_2> >
            >
        >
    > { };

    template<typename IntegralT, typename StringT>
    class string_to_integral_impl
    {
        BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((boost::is_integral<IntegralT>));

        typedef typename extract_actual_string<
            IntegralT,
            StringT
        >::type ExtractedStringT;
        BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((check_valid_characters<ExtractedStringT>));

        typedef typename accumulate_digits<
            IntegralT,
            ExtractedStringT
        >::type ValueT;

    public:
        typedef typename mpl::eval_if<
            is_negative<IntegralT, StringT>,
            mpl::negate<ValueT>,
            mpl::identity<ValueT>
        >::type type;
    };
}

template<typename IntegralT, typename StringT>
struct string_to_integral2
    : details::string_to_integral_impl<IntegralT, StringT>::type
{ };

template<typename IntegralT, int C0, int C1 = 0, int C2 = 0,
    int C3 = 0, int C4 = 0, int C5 = 0, int C6 = 0, int C7 = 0>
struct string_to_integral : string_to_integral2<
    IntegralT,
    boost::mpl::string<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7>
> { };
```

Usage would look like:

```
int i = string_to_integral<int, '4258','97'>::value;
// or
typedef boost::mpl::string<'4258','97'> str_t;
unsigned j = string_to_integral2<unsigned, str_t>::value;
```

Support for negative numbers is implemented, support for overflow detection is not (but your compiler will probably give a warning).

Comment: That's interesting, but what is `'4258'` ?

Comment: @kbok : `'4258','97'` is the way of representing the string literal `"425897"` in a way that's usable with `boost::mpl::string<>`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Are all those boost includes needed for that sample code? I think I remember why I hated using boost...

Comment: @kbok: `'1234'` is called a multicharacter literal. Their represantation as a `char` are basically implementation defined IIRC.

Comment: @Chuck: Since some Boost libraries, MPL, Spirit and the likes, are particularly heavy on the compiler and preprocessor, you only want to include the *absolute minimum* necessary. This can result in such a long `#include` list, and MPL forces it by not providing a simple `<mpl.hpp>` header that includes all other stuff. If you value your compile-time however, you'll gladly overlook the inconvenience of the includes.

Comment: @Xeo : You're correct that the representation is implementation-defined. Usually I would avoid posting answers containing such behavior, but in this case the Boost maintainers test the code extensively on enough platforms/compilers that I feel comfortable with it.

Comment: @ThatChuckGuy : In addition to what Xeo said, Boost is not a library, but a collection of libraries -- don't blame your dislike of Boost as a whole on designs of one library that you disliked.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe?

```
template<int C>
struct get_char
{
    static const int value = C - 48;
};

static_assert(get_char<'0'>::value == 0, "");
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if it is possible, but that is something you could try.

You can decrement the value of a character digit by '0' to obtain that value in numericals.

Like:

```
char a = '5';
int num =  a - '0';
```

That would solve your problem for one digit.

For you to solve a number with many digits (like "12345"), you would have to loop all the digits and sum the results (each one multiplied by 10^pos).

That would be easy to do in execution time, but in compile time it is not that simple.

"compile time recursion" may be your friend here. To be honest, I couldn't think in any solution using it, but you might find one.

Good luck!